# Fails loading dll library in Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits when run by Authenticated User

Tags: c#, dll, 64-bit, exe

Been struggling to resolve this issue for a while. any help will be much appreciated.

My windows application 'exe' fails to load following Dlls.
- zlib.dll and zlib1.dll (using DOTZLIB wrapper)

To briefly describe the running environment. (The application works perfectly with admin user accounts.)
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits
- User: Authenticated User (Not in Administrators Group)

However oddly enough, the program succeed to load the Dlls if run with parameters. 
i.e. c:> ApplicationName.exe "Filename.XXX" or double clicking on the filename.xxx.
Running the actual exe or its shortcut fails.

Could anyone shed some light on this problem?
Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Those dlls are definitely 64 bit?

Comment: Can't be 100% sure about that. Though in saying that it works perfectly on other 64 bits machine where the user has admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague. What do you mean "the application fails to load a DLL"? Does it crash?

It sounds like the application loads zlib if you open a file on startup. That makes sense to me... it won't load it until it needs it.

Comment: That's correct. This application can successfully load zlib only if I open a file on startup. But otherwise, if exe is run without opening a file it fails to load the dlls as soon as it try to open a file. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to load the dlls"? What behavior does the application exhibit?